# XSLT Convert element names to Pascal case

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following requirement:

```
<TAG_ONE>
<TAG_TWO>Abc</TAG_TWO>
<TAG_THREE>Xyz</TAG_THREE>
</TAG_ONE>
```

I need to convert this to following XML:

```
<TagOne>
<TagTwo>Abc</TagTwo>
<TagThree>Xyz</TagThree>
</TagOne>
```

XSLT 1.0 solution is preferred.

Basically the Element names should start from an upper case letter and each letter appear after an underscore should be upper case. then remove the underscores.
Note that this needs to be applied only to the element names and not to text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of work in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="new-name">
        <xsl:call-template name="PascalCase">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="name()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$new-name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PascalCase">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'_'"/>
    <xsl:param name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:param name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($token, 1, 1),  $lower-case, $upper-case)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($token, 2),  $upper-case, $lower-case)" />
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="PascalCase">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will only convert explicitly listed characters.

Comment: Good answer, although I'd apply templates to `"node() | @*"` just in case any have attributes, but as there's none in the OP's requirements, this might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is slightly shorter and more efficient than the currently accepted answer**.

It also works correctly in the case when the elements have attributes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="vEName"><xsl:call-template name="PCase"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$vEName}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="PCase">
    <xsl:param name="pName" select="translate(name(), $vUpper, $vLower)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pName">
      <xsl:variable name="vNextToken" select="substring-before(concat($pName, '_'), '_')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat(translate(substring($vNextToken,1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), 
              substring($vNextToken,2))"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="PCase">
        <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="substring-after($pName, '_')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the following XML document** (the provided one with an added attribute):

```
<TAG_ONE x="y">
    <TAG_TWO>Abc</TAG_TWO>
    <TAG_THREE>Xyz</TAG_THREE>
</TAG_ONE>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<TagOne x="y">
   <TagTwo>Abc</TagTwo>
   <TagThree>Xyz</TagThree>
</TagOne>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a quite complex XPath string concatenation of substrings this is possible. The implementation provided below works only if there is exactly one '_' underscore. For a more general case, the concatenation would have to be put in a separate named template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(name()='')]">
    <xsl:variable name="elemName">
      <xsl:call-template name="toLower">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="name()" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{concat(substring-before(concat(substring(name(),1,1),substring($elemName,2)),'_'),concat(substring(substring-after(name(),'_'),1,1),substring(substring-after($elemName,'_'),2)))}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="toLower">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($str,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" /> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: michael.hor257's approach is a more general solution.

Comment: "*The implementation provided below works only if there are 0 or 1 '_' underscores.*" I believe it works only if there is **exactly 1** delimiter.

Comment: Yep. I included that in the answer.